# Await the asynchronous dispatch of an action in redux-observable

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I have an epic which dispatches an action that is handled by a redux middleware, which returns a promise once the action is dispatched. The epic looks approximately like this:

```
const myEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(SAVE_ACTION),
    switchMap(action => [
      saveData(action.payload)
    ])
)
```

When the `SAVE_ACTION` is dispatched, it is picked up by the epic, which dispatches an action created by the `saveAction` action creator.

This resulting action is intercepted by a `redux` middleware (specifically [`redux-axios-middleware`](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware)) which does an HTTP request and converts the result of dispatching such action to a promise, which has the standard behavior of resolving when the HTTP request succeeds and rejecting when the HTTP request fails.

What I would need to do is do additional work once that promise is resolved, within this epic, because I need data contained both in the payload of the initial `SAVE_ACTION` action and the payload of the HTTP response.

Because the middleware also dispatches actions upon completion of the underlying HTTP request, it would be easy to write an additional epic to do the additional work I need to do in a distinct epic, but I wouldn't have access to the payload of the initial `SAVE_ACTION` anymore, so I'm trying to figure out if this can be handled all within a single epic, and I haven't found a way so far. I have found online posts like [this one](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/62#issuecomment-266337873), which is very informative, but still doesn't address the issue of awaiting the dispatch of an action, rather than a plain observable.

Comment: Why would you have a second middleware to handle your Ajax call, why not handle them within `redux-observable`?

Comment: You would have to ask the authors of the original code @Anas :) Let's just assume that there are more such epics than it's worth changing to use a different approach at triggering HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use merge like this:

```
 import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';

 const myEpic = action$ => {
     let initialPayload = null;      

     return merge(
         action$.pipe(
             ofType(SAVE_ACTION),
             switchMap(action => {
                 initialPayload = action.payload;

                 return [saveData(action.payload)]
             })
         ),

         action$.pipe(
             ofType(SAVE_ACTION_SUCCESS),
             mergeMap(action => {
                 // Use initialPayload here.
             })
         ),
    )
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I checked it out but I figured pretty soon that this still doesn't give me access to the payload of `SAVE_ACTION` in the second `action$.pipe`

Comment: @Simone Sorry forgot about that, modified the code. It's not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure that using mutable state to share data between two observables is a safe approach. For instance, there may be another `SAVE_ACTION` coming in while the first `SAVE_ACTION_SUCCESS` hasn't yet been dispacthed. I think you lose control of the flow basically